# NLTK - UnigramTagger: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm starting with NLTK and I'm following the NLTK book's instructions. In Chapter 5 (N-Gram Tagging) one can find the following code:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')
>>> brown_sents = brown.sents(categories='news')
>>> unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_tagged_sents)
>>> unigram_tagger.tag(brown_sents[2007])
[('Various', 'JJ'), ('of', 'IN'), ('the', 'AT'), ('apartments', 'NNS'),
('are', 'BER'), ('of', 'IN'), ('the', 'AT'), ('terrace', 'NN'), ('type', 'NN'),
(',', ','), ('being', 'BEG'), ('on', 'IN'), ('the', 'AT'), ('ground', 'NN'),
('floor', 'NN'), ('so', 'QL'), ('that', 'CS'), ('entrance', 'NN'), ('is', 'BEZ'),
('direct', 'JJ'), ('.', '.')]
>>> unigram_tagger.evaluate(brown_tagged_sents)
0.9349006503968017
```

I'm trying to do the same, but I want to take the whole Brown corpus to train the unigram tagger. For that I'm trying:

```
brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents()
brown_sents = brown.sents()

unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_tagged_sents)
unigram_tagger.tag(brown_sents)
unigram_tagger.evaluate(brown_tagged_sents)
```

But for some reason, I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/missogra/PycharmProjects/try/POS-Tagger-nltk.py", line 9, in <module>
    unigram_tagger.tag(brown_sents)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 63, in tag
    tags.append(self.tag_one(tokens, i, tags))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 83, in tag_one
    tag = tagger.choose_tag(tokens, index, history)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 142, in choose_tag
    return self._context_to_tag.get(context)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'd deeply appreciate any hint about why is this happening.

pyhon version 3.5

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are providing mutable list data where non-mutable data is needed. Tuples are non-mutables, lists are mutable. If you look carefully you see the `unigram_tagger.tag(brown_sents[2007])` is a list of tuples, your data is probably a list of lists. Havent used NLTK, cant help with code. Debug your data, see where lists are and convert to tuple before processing them: `data = [tuple(x) for x in ListOfLists]`

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I managed to make it work :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Patrick Artner's answer, I managed to resolved my problem like this:

```
brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents()
brown_sents = brown.sents()

unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_tagged_sents)
data = [tuple(sent) for sent in brown_sents]

unigram_tagger.tag(data)
print(unigram_tagger.evaluate(brown_tagged_sents))
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can check this answer as "self-answer" after I think 48h - wont give you creds but you get cred from upvotes by othters. +1 from me.

Comment: Maybe this might help too: https://github.com/alvations/spaghetti-tagger (shameless-plug)